# Background Image Won't Resize

Tags: css, background, resize

I'm using media queries to mobilize a website. Everything seems to be going fine except that the background image wont resize as the foreground image does at the top of the page. My media queries take effect at 650px and are in the file junkyardzombie.css at the bottom of the file. Can some please help me with this issue. The test site is at http://shoponlinedemo.com/junkyard-zombiez/

Comment: Try adding `background-size:contain;` Most likely this will distort your image though, so you're going to want to create different background images for the various screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you. This works great in chrome but not in FF or IE. Using background-size: cover does not work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was thinking that I should be able to apply width: auto on the proper div and get it to work. I was also thinking that the min-height attribute was preventing the image from scaling with the page when the browser window is below 650px.

Comment: UPDATE!!! Your fix is working on all 3 browsers now. Maybe the other browsers were cacheing. I dunno? But everything works now and I am very thankful for your assistance sir!!!

Comment: Great to hear, I will add my comment as an answer, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

By default, a background image is a static size(the size of the native image). You can control the size of a background image using the `background-size` property(read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)).

In this scenario, you can use `background-size:contain;` which will constrict the dimensions of the image to the width of the containing element(or to the width of the browser window if there is no containing element).